l3build - Speeding tests
I have too many slow tests because they are related to the PDF output. So, is there some tricks to "parallelize" or "multiprocess" tests?

For the latex test suite we parallize at a different level, split into multiple gh actions which can all run in parallel

In that case, is there a way to launch l3build ctan without testing anything? I do not find any advice about that in the l3build documentation.

@projetmbc No, quite deliberately all tests are run before building a release - we do no want to risk that something goes to CTAN that may be failing a test

OK, I'll change my workflow by testing in parallel, then once I'm reassured, I'll launch the CTAN process.

Not built-in, no. The entire setup for l3build is on the basis that we need to doing things one at a time to avoid as far as possible interference of one test with another. (Imagine both want to write to and read from the same auxiliary file, for example.) Admittedly, with multiple test directories, it might be feasible to arrange to run entirely separate test sets in parallel. However, that's quite niche and most of the time larger bundles are set up using some form of continuous integration system (GitHub, GitLab, etc.). Those allow one to run separate processes on separate virtual machines, meaning that splitting such as
l3build check -c build
l3build check -c second-test-dir

is possible. This is how the LaTeX team arrange to run the core format tests in parallel for routine testing - for building for release, they always run in serial by design.

Thanks for sharing your experience. Do you think it would be possible to adapt to l3build the process explained in the article “Fast regression testing of TeX packages: Multiprocessing and batching” in TUGboat 45:1, 2024? I am not thinking about a feature given by l3build because I know that there is a lot of ways to speed tests.
